# Couldn't able to load selected images to recycle view

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a jpg to pdf converter app so I want user to select images from their storage and after selecting images I want the users to show the images they selected in recycler view. For this I have created adapter and done the following

class MyAdapter (private var uri: ArrayList):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.myViewHolder>(){

```
class myViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    val titleImage:ImageView=itemView.imageView
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): myViewHolder {
    val itemView=LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.setimage,parent,false)
    return myViewHolder(itemView)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: myViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.titleImage.setImageURI(uri[position])
    Log.d("Check","onBindingViewHolder is working")
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return uri.size
}}
```

In the main Activity I have done as follow:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
private val PICK_IMAGE_CODE = 0
private lateinit var image: ArrayList<Uri>
val position=0

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    image= ArrayList()
    add.setOnClickListener{
        selectImage()
    }
    recyclerView.layoutManager=GridLayoutManager(this, 4)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    val adapter= MyAdapter(image)
    recyclerView.adapter=adapter
}

private fun selectImage() {
    val gallery = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
    gallery.setType("image/*")
    gallery.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true)
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(gallery, "Pictures: "), PICK_IMAGE_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    val adapter= MyAdapter(image)
    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && null != data){
            if (data.clipData != null){
                val count=data.clipData!!.itemCount
                for (i in 0 until count){
                    val imageUri= data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                    image.add(imageUri)
                    Log.d("Check",image.toString())
                }
            }
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Select a valid image",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }

}}
```

But Even after selecting the images It is not able to load images in Recycler View. Can anyone help me with that
Thanks for any suggestion...

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` in `onActivityResult()`.